# CondaValueError: The target prefix is the base prefix. Aborting

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have the following conda environment file `environment.yml`:

```
name: testproject
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- python=3.7
prefix: /opt/projects/testproject
```

Before creating the environment, only the base environment exists:

```
(base) me@mymachine:/opt/projects/testproject$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/anaconda/anaconda3
```

When trying to create the environment, I get the following error:

```
(base) me@mymachine:/opt/projects/testproject$ conda create -f environment.yml

CondaValueError: The target prefix is the base prefix. Aborting.
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You need to use

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Notice the extra `env` after `conda` and before `create`.

For more information check the [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file).

Comment: You can also get this error if you accidentally *reverse* the arguments: `conda create env -f environment.yml`. The correction remains the same.

Comment: Is it only me or syntax of conda is often confusing.

Comment: There are definitely a few commands that are quite confusing, especially around environment creation :-)

Comment: For me, the error was not using `-n` flag with the `conda create myenv`

Comment: Definitely confusing: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5253

Answer (score 52):

Very tricky, see the difference between the two:

```
conda create –-name my_env
```

and

```
conda create --name my_env
```

The first dash before `name` is slightly different (`–` instead of `-`). It takes me 15 mins to notice.

Comment: @jack would be more useful if you added the difference.

Comment: @suvy The first dash "–" is wrong, should be "-". I had this error because i copied from my notebook which has the auto format function and the dash was somehow converted there.

Comment: This could be an issue with env creation, but does not seem to relate to the question posted.

Comment: @HarrySalmon: I confirm this can be an issue with env creation (by copy-pasting the command from a blog or jupyter output, with the wrong dashes) that is one way to tickle the given CondaValueError in the title. That's in fact what led me to this question. So this answer does have value.

Answer (score 13):

You can use:

```
conda create --name nameOfEnv
```

Comment: This does not help as the OP asks for env create using an environment.yml

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue even with correct command syntax, right after the anaconda installation. The solution was to make the base environment not be activated on startup:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Then restart you terminal.
After that I've bean able to create my first conda environment.