# CondaValueError: The target prefix is the base prefix. Aborting. in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, admin, prompt

I've got following error when I try to make a virtual environment in **anaconda prompt which is executed with administrator**

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>d:

(base) D:\>cd anaconda

(base) D:\anaconda>cd Scripts

(base) D:\anaconda\Scripts>conda create -m ppt python=3.8

CondaValueError: The target prefix is the base prefix. Aborting.
```

How can I make a virtual environment in anaconda prompt in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CondaValueError: The target prefix is the base prefix. Aborting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56871882/condavalueerror-the-target-prefix-is-the-base-prefix-aborting)

Answer (score 2):

Create an environment in anaconda command prompt with the below command:

```
conda create -n myenv3.7 python=3.7
conda create myenv3.7
```

[image]

Similarly, you could try creating & activating an environment with python 3.8 with the below commands:

```
conda create -n myenv3.8 python=3.8
conda create myenv3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
conda create --name Envname
```

or

```
conda create -n ppt python=3.8
```

notice that you are writing `-m`